# OpenGL bitmap alpha buffer

Tags: opengl

I have two RGBA images (simple 2D raster of type GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, not textures or anything) of the same scene, one sharp, one blurred. With the blurred image displayed, I need to create an effect where the sharp image shows through in one or more (possibly overlapping) circular areas, smoothly blending with the background blurred image around the edges of the circles. I used to do the following.

Call this at the initialization:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

For every circle, make a copy of the sharp image, assign new values for their alpha components, starting from 255 at the center of the circle, reducing it to 0 towards the edges. Then rendered them one by one with `glDrawPixels()`, starting from the blurred image. It works, but as the number of those circular areas grows, it is getting noticeably slow.

I was thinking of using some alpha buffers (don't know the correct term), so that I create a small image with a cut out alpha circle in the middle, render its alpha component at one or several places of the framebuffer, then somehow blend the blurred image and the sharp image with those pre-rendered alpha values. So I wrote this in my `display()` function:

```
//render the alpha-mask first, at one place for now
GLfloat rp[4];
glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, rp);

glRasterPos2f(0.2f, 0.2f); //just some arbitrary coordinates on the screen
glColorMask(false, false, false, true); //think I only need the alpha-channel
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
glDrawPixels(sharp_mask_width, sharp_mask_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, alpha_mask);

//render the blurred image, blending the  the previously rendered alpha
glRasterPos2f(rp[0], rp[1]);

glColorMask(true, true, true, true); //all channels
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA); //make a hole where alpha mask had the maximum alpha
glDrawPixels(g_width, g_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageDataBlurred);

glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
glDrawPixels(g_width, g_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageDataSharp);
glFlush();
```

It seems I don't understand something important about all this blending stuff, because nothing is rendered at all, all I get is an empty screen. All I got is an effect remotely similar to what I need, messing with glBlendFunc parameters and blending rgb-s instead of alpha-s.

How, if at all, can it be done?

*I know I will probably burn in hell for using outdated OpenGL in the year 2015, when programmable shaders rule the world and cure cancer, but if possible I'd much prefer an answer describing how to do it in old style OpenGL, so I don't have to change that crap of a legacy program too much...*

Comment: Are you sure your framebuffer actually stores destination alpha? It's not needed for traditional alpha transparency, so sometimes you get a framebuffer that only stores r,g,b and then any attempt to later blend using destination alpha results in a constant **1.0** substituted for the non-existent alpha channel.

Comment: No, I am not sure. Is there a way to make it store destination alpha?

Comment: Since you are using deprecated OpenGL, you can use `GLuint alpha; glGetIntegerv (GL_ALPHA_BITS, &alpha);`. That's not supported anymore in modern GL and you have to use Framebuffer Objects to get that information, just sort of ignore that for now ;)